# Prevent html h2 tag being highlighted

Tags: html, css

I am using a `h2` tag under a picture that is part of the background as one of my buttons, the tag is just several `&nbsp` so there won't be anything there.

However if I click it twice, fast enough, it will highlight it, as if text was actually there, what can I do to prevent this?

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782

Comment: Why are you using an empty h2? That is a very inappropriate use of headings.

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible, what are you trying to achieve? Sounds like css could do the work for you

Comment: Im using an empty h2 because I don't want to use regular html buttons instead I have pictures for my buttons and the h2 behind it acts as the receiver of the click.

Comment: For buttons you should be using `button`, or if you actually mean links with a more decorative design then `a` is more appropriate. `h2` is not appropriate for this at all, and providing no text for something that is supposed to be interactive only makes it worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at [Tim Down's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting/4358620#4358620).

Quoted:

> In most browsers, this can be achieved using CSS:
>
> ```
> *.unselectable {
>    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
>    -khtml-user-select: none;
>    -webkit-user-select: none;
>    /*
>      Introduced in IE 10.
>      See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/
>    */
>    -ms-user-select: none;
>    user-select: none;
> }
> ```
>
> For IE < 10 and Opera, you will need to use the `unselectable` attribute of the element you wish to be unselectable. You can set this using an attribute in HTML:
>
> ```
> <div id="foo" unselectable="on">...</div>
> ```
>
> Sadly this property isn't inherited, meaning you have to put an attribute in the start tag of every element inside the `<div>`. If this is a problem, you could instead use JavaScript to do this recursively for an element's descendants:
>
> ```
> function makeUnselectable(node) {
>     if (node.nodeType == 1) {
>         node.setAttribute("unselectable", "on");
>     }
>     var child = node.firstChild;
>     while (child) {
>         makeUnselectable(child);
>         child = child.nextSibling;
>     }
> }
>
> makeUnselectable(document.getElementById("foo"));
> ```

Comment: You forgot to mention `unselectable` as also mentioned in [Tim Down's stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/826782/681807). You should have copied all of it and then given him credit - do you not know how referencing works?

Comment: Sorry, got this from my own code, please enlighten me with how I can reference to other answers, for future questions.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use a `h2` for a button. It is used for defining headers, which define the structure of your document.

If you want a button that is actually an image, do something like:

```
<button id="myButton">Do something</button>

#myButton {
    width: 50px; height: 20px; //the dimensions of your image
    background: url(myimage.png); //the URL of your image
    border: none; //hiding default button borders
    text-indent: -999em; //hiding the default text
}
```

The default text is needed for accesibility. People with a screen reader should be aware what your button does. This way you can also keep other useful properties of your button (like having a tabindex, being able to get focus, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of (ab)using the `h2` tag by filling it with `&nbsp;`s to create a gap, you should find a better way to achieve the desired effect.

Perhaps a `margin-bottom` on your picture will have the same effect?